# IE7 & 8 defaulting to smallest stylesheet on bones wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, media-queries

I am skinning up a wordpress theme using the bones responsive theme as a boilerplate. The theme however fails in IE7 and 8 due to the browsers rendering the smallest stylesheet option. Basically it inherits all the base styles and none from the 768up.css and 1080up.css.

I've had a look around thinking there would be some documentation about this but cant find any.

The bones theme can be found here http://themble.com/bones/

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Media Queries aren't supported in IE 7 + 8. I learn this the hard way a few months back.

I got them working using the excellent Respond.js.

http://responsejs.com/

**EDIT:** I'm not too familiar with Wordpress but it looks like there is a plugin for this - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/respondjs/

Comment: I ahve tried this and it didnt make a difference, I guess it might be something to do with the theme. This is the answer but I've jsut hardcoded the main css for lt IE9

Comment: Did you set respond.js up properly? It should allow for media query support in older IE versions regardless of the theme.

Comment: well as it's just a wordpress plugin it should do everything for you. I tried setting it up manually too with no result. I am only testing this using IE tester so it may be that IE tester is bugging out the JS which is not uncommon.

Comment: Good point. Have you got an old copy of IE you could use? I don't trust IE Tester. I've got an Oracle VM running XP with IE 6, 7, and 8 on which seems like overkill but is invaluable.

Comment: Im on a mac but I have a vm running windows 7 that had IE8 on it which is fine. Windows update ran and pushed it to IE9 thought<-- hate windows for stuff like this.

Comment: You need XP for the older versions which is a pain. This is meant to be good but I've not used it - http://www.browserstack.com/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13303/discussion-between-matt-wade-and-spacebeers)

Comment: If you have IE9 you can switch to IE7 or IE8 mode via developer tools, you don't need IE tester for this.

Comment: @x64igor - Those two modes are useless. Compare them to the actual browsers.

Comment: @SpaceBeers Do you have a website url on which I could see some difference?

Comment: I've not got access to my VM now but this should do for now - http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/02/reliable-cross-browser-testing-part-1-internet-explorer/